# Opencart 2.3.0.2 : sockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known Error

Tags: email, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to send mail using opencart for that I have configured mail setting in system > setting > mail .

Here is my mail configure:

[image]
But when A new user register instead of sending Mail I've seen the following Error:

> fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such
>   host is known.

Here is the snap of Error:
[image]

If anyone solve the error please help me to solve it out.

Comment: Which version of xampp? What version of PHP? Which version of Opencart? Looks like the host DNS could be failing so mail may need to be configured or a firewall issue possibly.

Comment: Opencart 2.3.0.2 , XAMPP 3.2.2 , PHP 5.5.37